# How to Register Multiple Sidebars at once in functions.php

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to register multiple sidebars at once and access theme by different id's just like we are registering multiple menus at once i.e. Main-Menu and Footer-menu.

`<?php register_nav_menus(array('primary-menu' => 'Main-Menu','secondary-menu' => 'Footer-menu')); ?>`

- How we will do this with sidebars as well.We just write one line code
  and register multiple sidebars at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the WordPress native function [register_sidebars()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebars/).

You will be able to register multiple sidebars at once as your menus.

```
register_sidebars( 2, array(
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget %d">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',        
    'name'=>__( 'My sidebar %d', 'textdomain' )   
);
```

The [register_sidebar()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/) function is a better way to achieve this but it takes more than 1 line.

Comment: But please right me the one line code for it. This is also I know how to register but the point is that how to register multiple sidebars with one line of register sidebar() function. Just like I already mentioned in the multiple menus.